Show that the jump $j_f(c)$ of increasing $f$ at $c$ is given by $\inf\{f(y)-f (x): x < c < y, x, y \in I\}$.

Let $I\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be an interval and let $f: I \to \mathbb{R}$ be increasing on $I$. If $c$ is not an endpoint of $I$, show that the jump $j_f(c)$ of $f$ at $c$ is given by $\inf\{f(y)-f (x): x < c < y, x, y \in I\}$.

Let $A = \{f(y):y \in I, y > c\}$ and $\inf\{f(y):y \in I, y > c\} = w$
Let $B = \{f(x):x \in I, x < c\}$ and $\sup \{f(x):x \in I, x < c\} = h$
Let $C = \{f(y)-f(x): x < c < y, x, y \in I\}$ and $\inf\{f(y)-f(x): x < c < y, x, y \in I\} = k$
The jump is defined as $j_f(c) = \lim_{x\to c^{+}}f(x) - \lim_{x\to c^{-}}f(x) = \inf\{f(x):x \in I, x > c\} - \sup \{f(x):x \in I, x < c\} = w - h$
$j_f(c) = w - h \le f(y) - h \le f(y) - f(x)$ for any $y > c$ and $c > x$ from $x, y \in I$. So, $j_f(c)$ is a lower bound for $C$. Hence, $j_f(c) \le k$.
We want to show that $j_f(c) = w - h \ge k$
Let $v < f(y) - f(x)$. Then $v$ is a lower bound on $C$ and so $v \le k$.
From $v < f(y) - f(x)$ we have $f(x) < f(y) - v$. $f(y) - v < h, f(y) < h + v$.
Frankly, I am stuck at this point. I am trying somehow to incorporate the fact that $f(y) > f(x)$ for all $y > c$ and $x < c$ (since the function is increasing). However, all the trials were wrong.

It is enough to show the following.

If $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $\mathbb R$ such that $\inf(A)$ and $\sup(B)$ make sense, then $\inf(A-B)=\inf(A)-\sup(B)$, where $A-B=\{a-b\mid a\in A,b\in B\}$.

It is clear that $\inf(A)-\sup(B)$ is a lower bound since $a\geq\inf(A)$ and $-b\geq -\sup(B)$ for any $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.
Take a lower bound for $A-B$, say $c$. Then, $c\leq a-b$ for every $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. Then, $a\ge c+\sup(B)$ for all $a\in A$ so $c+\sup(B)$ is a lower bound for $A$. Then, $c+\sup(B)\leq\inf(A)$, or $c\leq\inf(A)-\sup(B)$.
Therefore, $\inf(A)-\sup(B)=\inf(A-B)$.
Hope this helps. :)

Thank you for your answer. As I said I have tried multiple approaches including this one, too. Since this is a comment let's write it consciously. Let $v = c, f(y) = a, f(x) = b$, then we have $v \le f(y) - f(x), f(y) \ge v + h, v + h \le w$ **Then I stupidly concluded that **$v \le h-w$ and hence $j_f(c) = w-h \le -v$. Which was not solving my problem. I was working on this for $2$ hours. Thank you very much! You saved me several additional hours of work!
